# What is the conclusion from cross validation scores?

Tags: classification, predictive-models, boosting, hyperparameter

I am training a model, and I'm using an xgboost model.
I used the following piece of code to find the cross-validation score
score=cross_val_score(final_classifier, X, y, cv=5, scoring="f1")
and I get the following result

```
score=array([0.51165018, 0.97186588, 0.97350451, 0.9742288 , 0.85236734])
```

On the training data, I get the results as follows.

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      0.98      0.99     44959
           1       0.98      1.00      0.99     44959

    accuracy                           0.99     89918
   macro avg       0.99      0.99      0.99     89918
weighted avg       0.99      0.99      0.99     89918
```

What is the conclusion from these results?
One of my cross-val score is very low (0.51) compared to others, and in the entire training data, I have 99% accuracy.
What hyperparameter should I tune to improve the results?

Comment: What's the size of the dataset? Its likely that the dataset is small and/or the distribution is quite varied, hence the wide variation in cross-validation scores

Comment: @shark8me 89918 balanced dataset

Comment: its possible that the random splits done by the cross validation resulted in some splits having a different distribution. What happens if you re-run cross validation multiple times?